# How can I be more visible to have an answer at my question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

By curiosity, is there a way to get attention to obtain an answer by someone, if nobody answered or even comment ?

It could be by placing this question on the top of the active questions, by an action of the user.

I think some questions deserve to be answered and can help other people.

Comment: You can't insist anything.  Everyone here volunteers there time, so why should you get to demand someone answer your question instead of someone else's?  But there are ways to get [attention to an older, possibly forgotten post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions)

Comment: You can place a bounty but really the emphasis is on you to provide a good question that people can answer. No question is entitled to an answer

Comment: I didn't mean insist in a bad way, I'm aware that people are volunteers, I think I'm part of these. I mean get attention, be visible as you suggest psubsee2003. Thank you for the link, interesting.

Comment: Okay maybe I will try to place a bounty

Comment: @tomahim sorry if the tone sounded harsh, but there are many users who come and expect (re:demand) answers.  But one thing you need to consider is maybe the question isn't good enough.  Often if a question gets little attention, it is possible it is off-topic or unclear.  Editing before you place a bounty to make sure everything is perfectly clear and well explained can do wonders.

Comment: As the poor french that I am, the term "insist" was not right I guess. Yes maybe unclear and in some case too specific and complex to attract people.

Answer (score 1):

If you feel a question hasn't got enough attention you can place a [bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) on it; by doing this you offer some of your own reputation to make the question more visible. Remember though there are no garentees and more attention may not lead to answers.

No question is entitled to an answer however, and you should take it upon yourself to make your questions as clear and answerable as possible; remember we're all volunteers